# ASP.NET CORE 5 MVC How To Link NavBar to Views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linker, categories, uploading

I have created a project in which I can upload, download, delete and preview files. Now , I want to create a nav-bar for categories, so that the uploader can upload a file ONLY to a SPECIFIC category, so when the user comes in on the site and he wants to access that document, he will have to click on that specific category in the navbar and only then have the document displayed, after clicking on the cateogry. How can I do that? I will leave my razor page and controller code below, thank you so much in advance!:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        FileClass fc = new FileClass();
        List<Admin> adminModels = new List<Admin>();
        interface Iuser
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
            void IsEqualTo();
        }
        class User : Iuser
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }



            public void IsEqualTo()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        class Admin : Iuser
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
            public void IsEqualTo()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _iweb;

        public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment iweb)
        {
            _iweb = iweb;

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IFormFile fifile)
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(fifile.FileName);

            var fisave = Path.Combine(_iweb.WebRootPath, "Uploads", fifile.FileName);
            var stream = new FileStream(fisave, FileMode.Create);
            await fifile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            stream.Close();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            var displayfc = Path.Combine(_iweb.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(displayfc);
            List<FileInfo> fileinfo = di.GetFiles().ToList(); ;
            FileClass.Filename = fileinfo;
            return View();
        }
       


        public IActionResult Delete(string filedel)
        {
            filedel = Path.Combine(_iweb.WebRootPath, "Uploads", filedel);
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filedel);
            if (fi != null)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(filedel);
                fi.Delete();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        public IActionResult DocumentViewer(string fileview)
        {

            return View(fc);
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)
        {
            if (filename == null)
                return Content("filename is not avaiable");
            var path = Path.Combine(_iweb.WebRootPath, "Uploads", filename);

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
        private string GetContentType(string path)
        {
            var types = GetMimeTypes();
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
            return types[ext];
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetMimeTypes()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {".txt", "text/plain"},
                {".pdf", "application/pdf"},
                {".doc", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".docx", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
                {".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
                {".png", "image/png"},
                {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".gif", "image/gif"},
                {".csv", "text/csv"}
            };
        }

        [HttpGet("denied")]
        public IActionResult Denied()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public IActionResult Secured()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet("login")]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnURL"] = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Validate(string username, string password, string returnUrl)
        {

            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            List<Iuser> utilizatori = new List<Iuser>();
            utilizatori.Add(new User() { username = "username", password = "password" });
            utilizatori.Add(new Admin() { username = "bobitza", password = "28" });
            utilizatori.Add(new Admin() { username = "rares", password = "cretin" });

            foreach (Iuser user in utilizatori)
            {
                if (user.username == username && user.password == password)
                {
                    if (user is User)
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim>();
                        claims.Add(new Claim("username", username));
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
                        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
                        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
                    }
                    else if (user is Admin)
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim>();
                        claims.Add(new Claim("username", username));
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
                        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
                        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
                    }

                }
            }





            TempData["Error"] = "Error. Username or Password is invlaid";
            return View("login");
        }
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
```

and here is the razor page

```
<center>
    <h1>Daca nici acu nu merge ... ma sinucid</h1>
    <h2>Sa moara mama</h2>
    <hr />
    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
<form methord="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
    <input type="file" name="fifile" />
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Meniu de navigare</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

    <hr />
</form>}
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>

        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in FileClass.Filename)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td><a href="@Url.Action("Download","Home",new { filename=item.Name })">Download</a></td>
                @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    <td><a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Home", new { filedel = item.Name })">Delete</a></td>
                }
                <td><a href="/Home/DocumentViewer/@item.Name">Viewer</a></td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</center>
```

and here is the file model

```
public class FileClass
    {
        public static List<FileInfo> Filename { get; set; } = new List<FileInfo>();
    }
```

Comment: Keep a hidden field in your form with the value of the category the user selected and you should receive it in your controller.

Comment: Could you please be a little more precise? Thank you!